# How to use FCM to push notification to user device without using firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications, google-cloud-functions

How do i push notification to a device using `FCM` without using `Firebase` as a backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fcm it`s a independent package and you can use fcm without firebase

you can use this package (follow Readme steps)

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

and this tutorial

https://medium.com/@jun.chenying/flutter-tutorial-part3-push-notification-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-2fbdd84d3a5e

you should save fcm tokens in your database for sending notification per device or send mass notification without fcm tokens